# Sorting associated objects based on the association's creation date

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Right now, I'm working on a simple app. It requires to get the associated objects ordered by the date that they we're added to the object. For that, I want to order them based on the pivot-table's id.

My app looks a bit like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

However, when a user wants to buy a product, I would add a new relation into the pivot table `courses_users`. When I then run `@product.users`, I will get them back in the order the users where created, not added as the relation.

I've tried creating a query scope, but it didn't work. I also tried to create a order on the `has_and_belongs_to_many`, as such:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, order: 'course_users.id ASC'
```

But none of that seemed to work, no `ORDER` statement could be found in the logs.

Comment: A HABTM relation table may or may not have an `:id` primary key. Can you post the schema? I believe by default it does not. You could add one, or you could add a `:created_at` timestamp for each item in the pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the created_at field to your table.

```
rails g migration AddTimestampsToCourseUsers created_at:datetime
```

then you can

```
@product.users.order "course_users.created_at ASC"
```